# App should go to a different route when fetched dropdown values are clicked

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to redirect users in my react app to a certain route in my app or a site say google when you pick the value from the dropdown. I'm populating the dropdown by fetching the data from an api

I've tried adding an If then returning the fetched data from the api but that only renders the the value specified in the if as shown below.

```
if (item.Name === 'MTN') {
  console.log('works');
  return <option value="/">{item.Name}</option>;
}
```

```
componentDidMount() {
  getTheSimProviders().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: false,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        airtime: data[0].Merchants,
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Method that redirects a user once an item from the dropdown is selected:

```
onUrlSelected(e) {
  console.log(`The value is: ${e.target.value}`);
  window.location = `${e.target.value}`;
}
```

How I'm rendering the data from the dropdown:

```
<div className="row">
  <h3 className="select-headings">Airtime & Data</h3>
  <select onChange={this.onUrlSelected} className="select">
    {this.state.airtime.map(item => {
      if (item.Name === 'MTN') {
        console.log('to jesus be my glory');
      }
      return <option value="/">{item.Name}</option>;
    })}
  </select>
</div>
```

I would also appreciate if someone could show me how to do it onsubmit with a button

Comment: Any errors? What does this show `console.log('The value is: ${e.target.value}');` ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to redirect on each element to "/"?? I think it should be something like this: `value={item.URL}`

Comment: @HRK44 it shows the home page as the value I put is "/"

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia item.URL will redirect to the url in the api, I want the selected item  to redirect to it's associated page route in my application when the option is chosen

Answer (score 0):

You can use onsubmit on tag form and add a button into the form to submit it.

```
<form onSubmit={this.onUrlSelected}>
   <select  className="select">
     {this.state.airtime.map(item => 
        <option key={item.key} value="/">{item.Name}</option>;
     })}
   </select>
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Don't forget to use a unique key for each item on map function.

Comment: thanks. how would i specify the value is a link to a new route in my application?

Comment: you can add an onChange function to <select> tag, and in this function you'll get selected value each change. If you stores it in the component state with setState. you can then onSubmit send this value from state object.